# BigCommerce API Update Order with PUT

Tags: filemaker, bigcommerce

I need to update an order which is done via PUT method passing the order id as part of the https url string and a single parameter, the status_id.
https://mystore.mybigcommerce.com/orders/12345.json

I have tried several methods to pass the status_id value but no matter what I try "status_id=12" or formatted as JSON "{"status_id": 12,}" I always get the same response: 
 [{"status":415,"message":"The specified input content type is not valid."}]

I have also tried as a POST request passing the JSON or XML code as raw data but that method is not supported.

How am I supposed to pass that field=value pair? can I embed it in the url string?
I also tried it but it wouldn't work for me.

Any ideas?

In case you are wondering I am doing it within FileMaker with TROIUrl plugIn, not a very popular technology, but the GET method retrieving orders works like a charm
TURL_Put( ""; $url ;"status_id=12")   (I have also tried other FM plugIns to no avail)
Don't get too caught up in the Filemaker part, I don't expect many people out there to be familiar with BigCommerce and Filemaker. I just need a generic answer.

Thanks

Comment: Try setting the headers to content-type JSON. Also, your json string might have a typo '{"status_id":12}'

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Commandline tool `curl` is worth a try. It supports `put` and `https`.

Mac OS X: curl already installed, call from FileMaker via AppleScript `do shell script`.

Windows: must be installed, call via Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using { "status_id": "3" } which means you probably need to put quotes around the actual number.

Also, it is a PUT operation and application/json which is part of the request content.

Answer (score 0):

The error message received by the OP:

```
[{"status":415,"message":"The specified input content type is not valid."}]
```

Is saying that he did not supply the 'Content-Type' header in his request or that the header supplied is for a content type that is not allowed.  For the OP's case using JSON he would need to include the header:

```
    Content-Type: application/json
```

in his HTTPS request.  This description can be found along with those of the other status codes you may see here:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/status-codes